# Is there a way, in the web console, to sort files in a google storage bucket according to date, size, type, etc

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-console

Can't find any reference to this. Seems like a basic capability of any file storage in general.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no way to sort the files or folders inside a bucket on the Cloud Console.

You can always do by coding a sorting routine:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId = 'YOUR PROJECT';

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: projectId,
});

// The name for the new bucket
const bucketName = 'YOUR-BUCKET';
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
bucket.getFiles(null, (err,data) => {
    data.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.metadata.updated > b.metadata.updated) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (a.metadata.updated < b.metadata.updated) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
    for (file of data) {
        console.log(` ${file.metadata.name} - ${file.metadata.updated}`);
    }
});
```

There is a Feature request but seems that is not updated.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119209458

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative is using the command line for this(gcloud/gsutil)**

Assuming you have gcloud already installed... do next:

Using terminal(check/set) GCP project you are logged in:

`$> gcloud config list` - to check if you are using the proper GCP project.

`$> gcloud config set project <your_project_id>` - to set required project

Get the total bucket/folder size:

```
gsutil du -sah gs://bucket_name/folder1
```

List objects sorted by date ascending:

```
gsutil ls -l gs://bucket_name/folder1/folder2 | sort -k 2
```

List objects sorted by size descending:

```
gsutil du -ah gs://bucket_name/folder1/folder2/* | sort -k 2
```

List unique objects by prefix(for example object name pattern: twitter_2020-09-03-03-01-10.csv, facebook_2020-09-03-03-01-11.csv):

```
gsutil ls gs://bucket_name/folder_name | sed 's/_.*//' | uniq
```

> Here (in the last example) if you have multiple twitter, facebook files in that folder the result will be:

```
gs://bucket_name/folder_name/twitter
gs://bucket_name/folder_name/facebook
```

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud added the ability to do this, but it's a bit hidden. You want to click on the dropdown right above the directory listing where it says `Filter by name prefix only` and then you can select `Sort and filter`. After that you should be able to click on a column to sort by that column.

Google Cloud warns that this will make the UI slower.